# Linear warping of pandas time-series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame, df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

s  = np.arange(5)
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in s:
    s_df = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.arange(100),
                         'x':np.arange(100),
                         'y':np.arange(100),
                         'r':np.random.randint(60,100)})
    s_df['unit'] = str(i)
    df = df.append(s_df)
```

I want select the 'x' and 'y' data for each 'unit', from 'time' 0 up until its value of 'r', and then warp the selected data to fit a new normalized timescale of 0-100. The new DataFrame should look the same, but x and y will have been stretched to fit the new timescale.

Comment: What is your expected output from this dataset?  If you don't mind please use np.random.seed(123) to fix the random element.  Thanks.

Comment: The new data frame should look the same, but 'x' and 'y', which will be of different lengths once selected with respect to their 'r', will have been warped to fit 'time', meaning their slopes should all be slightly different when plotted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start with this and modify:

```
df.groupby('unit', as_index=False, group_keys=False)\
  .apply(lambda g: g[g.time <= g.r.max()].pipe(lambda x: x.assign(x = np.interp(x.time * 100/x.r.max(), g.time, g.x),
                                                                  y = np.interp(x.time * 100/x.r.max(), g.time, g.y))))
```

Output:

```
     r  time         x         y unit
0   91     0  0.369445  0.802790    0
1   91     1  0.802881  0.411523    0
2   91     2  0.080290  0.228482    0
3   91     3  0.248865  0.624470    0
4   91     4  0.350376  0.207805    0
5   91     5  0.604447  0.495269    0
6   91     6  0.402430  0.317250    0
7   91     7  0.205757  0.296371    0
8   91     8  0.426954  0.793716    0
9   91     9  0.728095  0.486691    0
10  91    10  0.087941  0.701258    0
11  91    11  0.653719  0.937834    0
12  91    12  0.702571  0.381267    0
13  91    13  0.113419  0.492686    0
14  91    14  0.381172  0.539422    0
15  91    15  0.490320  0.166290    0
16  91    16  0.440490  0.029675    0
17  91    17  0.663973  0.245057    0
18  91    18  0.273116  0.280711    0
19  91    19  0.807658  0.869288    0
20  91    20  0.227972  0.987803    0
21  91    21  0.747295  0.526613    0
22  91    22  0.491929  0.118479    0
23  91    23  0.403465  0.564284    0
24  91    24  0.618359  0.648467    0
25  91    25  0.867436  0.447866    0
26  91    26  0.487128  0.526473    0
27  91    27  0.135412  0.855466    0
28  91    28  0.469281  0.753690    0
29  91    29  0.397495  0.786670    0
..  ..   ...       ...       ...  ...
53  82    53  0.985053  0.534743    4
54  82    54  0.255997  0.789710    4
55  82    55  0.629316  0.889916    4
56  82    56  0.730672  0.539548    4
57  82    57  0.484289  0.278669    4
58  82    58  0.120573  0.754350    4
59  82    59  0.071606  0.912240    4
60  82    60  0.126613  0.775831    4
61  82    61  0.392633  0.706384    4
62  82    62  0.312653  0.698514    4
63  82    63  0.164337  0.420798    4
64  82    64  0.655284  0.317136    4
65  82    65  0.526961  0.484673    4
66  82    66  0.205197  0.516752    4
67  82    67  0.405965  0.314419    4
68  82    68  0.892710  0.620090    4
69  82    69  0.351876  0.422846    4
70  82    70  0.601449  0.152340    4
71  82    71  0.187239  0.486854    4
72  82    72  0.757108  0.727058    4
73  82    73  0.728311  0.623236    4
74  82    74  0.725225  0.279149    4
75  82    75  0.536730  0.746806    4
76  82    76  0.584319  0.543595    4
77  82    77  0.591636  0.451003    4
78  82    78  0.042806  0.766688    4
79  82    79  0.326183  0.832956    4
80  82    80  0.558992  0.507238    4
81  82    81  0.303649  0.143872    4
82  82    82  0.303214  0.113151    4

[428 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Great, although time should remain the same and the x and y values should be warped

Comment: @jtm_beta What is the formula you want to use to warp x and y?  I don't understand this concept right now.

Comment: In a previous and long winded implementation I used np.linspace and np.interp. The above result is what i'm looking for, but it is both the x and y data that should change. So the shape of the new DataFrame will be the same, but the slope of x and y will have changed. i'm afraid I don't know the formula

Comment: @jtm_beta See edit, I am not certain that is exactly what you need.